# LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _main in .dll with DllMain declared?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I am getting the error on compile in VS:

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol _main File: MSVCRT.lib(exe_main.obj)

This error only occurs when compiling in Release x86, and not Debug x86.

```
 #include "includes.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
    HINSTANCE handle,
    DWORD fdwReason,
    LPVOID lpReserved) 
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, directxThread, 0, 0, 0);
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: A problem in your project settings, that we can't see

Comment: Project > Properties > General > "Application Type" setting.  Making the change for the Debug configuration and forgetting to make it as well for the Release configuration is a standard mistake.  Upper-left combo.  Do favor the right project template so you don't have to change it.

Comment: Is it possible your IDE is configured in Release x86 to compile an exe (cli / windows application)?

Comment: Are you deliberately [setting up a deadlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices)?

Comment: @EthanHammond Has this issue been solved?

Answer (score -1):

This is likely a problem with your IDE/compiler command. If possible, you should check the exact command sent to [cl.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options?view=vs-2019) (the Microsoft compiler) when release mode is enabled, and ensure that MSVCRT.lib is present in the compiler command. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-lib-files-as-linker-input?view=vs-2019) for more information.

If MSVCRT.lib is not in your compile command, you will have to add MSVCRT.lib as an additional input/dependency to your compiler in your project settings, if you're using an IDE like Visual Studio. If you're using the command line, you can simply add the term.